# Solving for the variable M?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have this equation and I'm trying to solve for $M$ but it is not working out. Can someone please help me?

$$ \frac{M}{M^2 + 1} = \epsilon .$$

Comment: $\epsilon M^2 - M + \epsilon = 0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the denominator out to get $M=\epsilon M^2+\epsilon$ and then use the quadratic equation.